# Spring Batch processing

Tags: spring-batch

I am reading 10000 records from database. But, I would like to process 5 records only.

What can I do to process only 5 records in Spring Batch ? I would like my .processor(processor()) to execute only 5 times. Here is my code

```
 @Bean
  public Step step1(ItemWriter<BillerOrder> writer) {
      return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")             
              .<BillerOrder, BillerOrder> chunk(1)
              .reader((ItemReader<? extends BillerOrder>) reader())
              .processor(processor())
              .writer(writer)
              .build();
  }
```

I would like my .processor(processor()) to execute only 5 times.

Comment: Could you ask why?

Comment: Why are you reading 10.000 records if you want to process only 5?

Comment: We are running applications in one production server, so in order to avoid processing large data while other applications are running in the same server, I would like to run small amount of records at a time. Yes, I can limit the records in sql query. But, I was thinking if there is mechanism to do in Spring Batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes, I can limit the records in sql query. But, I was thinking if there is mechanism to do in Spring Batch.

You can write a custom `CompletionPolicy` or use a `ItemReadListener` that stops the step after 5 records, but I would *not* recommend that. The clean way to address your use case is to limit the number of items in your query (ie read only items that need to be processed).